# JQuery request to get more than 10 RSS feeds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a RSS Reader and I got a singular problem: when I do a feed request, it just returns me 10 elements, even if there are lots more to download. I'm pretty sure it's a parameter about it, but I can't get it.

Here's the code

```
urlNews : "http://www.androidworld.it/feed?limit=90",
urlRecensioni : "",
newsNonLette : 0,
recensioniNonLette : 0,

scaricaNews : function(){
    //scarica la lista delle news
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : feed.urlNews,
        success : function(response){
            utils.debug("feed.scaricaNews (success)");
        },
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            //xhr.responseText
            utils.debug("feed.scaricaNews (error): " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the feed you're using is generated by Wordpress, the argument you need is `paged={page number goes here}`, so for example,

```
http://www.androidworld.it/feed/?limit=90&paged=2
```

returns different stories than

```
http://www.androidworld.it/feed/?limit=90&paged=3
```

Comment: No guess - that's how Wordpress Atom feeds work.  The question should have probably been filed under Wordpress based on the "generated by" tag in the feed...

Comment: Yes it probably should have been

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be your code's fault.

I get only 10 items from the RSS feed you show, no matter what I specify in `limit`. You probably  need to ask the site's operators for the right parameter.

Answer (score 1):

**This has nothing to do with Javascript or AJAX.**

Your first debugging step is to check the source data, for which all you need to do is go to to `http://www.androidworld.it/feed/?limit=90` in your browser. And, as you can see, the server only provides up to 10 feed items.

This is pretty common; you should contact the provider of the feed to request increasing that limit, or to find out whether they support further parameters (such as `paged`, which is sometimes available to navigate through a resultset in chunks).

Please, next time, do the basic debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I sincerely didn't know such a parameter and asked here after 2 days and I thought it was the best thing to ask here :) Many thanks for the reply :)